# Links inside 2 nested css grids do not work

Tags: css-grid

screen shot of navigation menu:

[image]

I created two grids as shown below, the first to layout the page and second to layout the menu items. I want the header to remain in place at the top. The links no longer work.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    background-color: #F2E1D4;
}
main {
  overflow: auto;
}
.nav-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 120px 80px 180px 150px 140px 160px 40px 40px 5px 1fr;  
    grid-gap: 10px;
.nav-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;    
    letter-spacing: .08rem;    
    color: #4f271b;
    font-weight: 700;
     margin-top: 10vh; 
  
}
.nav-image {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}
-------------------
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="nav-container">
        <div id="margin"></div> 
        <div  class="nav-text"><a href="Our-Story.html"></a>OUR STORY</div>
        <div  class="nav-text" ><a href="#"></a>FARM</div>
        <div  class="nav-text"><a href="#"></a>FARMERS MARKET</div>

        <div class ="nav-image"> <img src = "resources/images/MSW_Logo/MSW_LOGO_B_RGB.png" width=150px height=auto alt="Morningstar logo" > </div> 
        <div  class="nav-text"><a href="#"></a>WOOL/TEXTILE</div>
        <div  class="nav-text"><a href="#"></a>CONNECT</div>
        <div class="nav-text"> <img src = "resources/images/MSW_SOCIAL_Logos/Intsa_BROWN.png" width=20px, height=auto> </div>
        <div class="nav-text"> <img src =  "resources/images/MSW_SOCIAL_Logos/Pinterest_p_BROWN.png" width=25px, height=auto> </div>
        <div class="nav-text"> <img src = "resources/images/MSW_SOCIAL_Logos/newsletter_icon_BROWN.png" width=25px, height=auto> </div>


    </nav>
  <main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your links do not work because you put their text outside of the `<a></a>` tags. You have to put it between the tags like this:

```html
<a href="#">FARM</a>
```

Here is your code with the links working as expected:

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    background-color: #F2E1D4;
}
main {
  overflow: auto;
}
.nav-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 120px 80px 180px 150px 140px 160px 40px 40px 5px 1fr;  
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.nav-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;    
    letter-spacing: .08rem;    
    color: #4f271b;
    font-weight: 700;
     margin-top: 10vh; 
  
}
.nav-image {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <nav class="nav-container">
      <div id="margin"></div>
      <div class="nav-text"><a href="Our-Story.html">OUR STORY</a></div>
      <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">FARM</a></div>
      <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">FARMERS MARKET</a></div>
      <div class ="nav-image"><img src = "resources/images/MSW_Logo/MSW_LOGO_B_RGB.png" width=150px height=auto alt="Morningstar logo" > </div>
      <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">WOOL/TEXTILE</a></div>
      <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">CONNECT</a></div>
      <div class="nav-text"><img src = "resources/images/MSW_SOCIAL_Logos/Intsa_BROWN.png" width=20px, height=auto> </div>
      <div class="nav-text"><img src =  "resources/images/MSW_SOCIAL_Logos/Pinterest_p_BROWN.png" width=25px, height=auto> </div>
      <div class="nav-text"><img src = "resources/images/MSW_SOCIAL_Logos/newsletter_icon_BROWN.png" width=25px, height=auto> </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even see it!